# How should I bind new view components to the presenter in GWT's MVP pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, gwt, mvp

I been reading through [Large scale application development and MVP](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture.html) and I was wondering how you guys deals with dynamically added components within this suggested way of implementing the pattern.

Lets say you have a table, where you have three buttons in each table row, and table rows can be added dynamically. How would you guys suggest binding these to the presenter?

The new row, if following Google's proposed structure, will get generated in the view, which does not have a direct link to the presenter and can not call back to it (so no calling `bindNewButtons(Button, Button, Button)`-ish type method).

So, what's good practice here? I was thinking since the presenter will be handling the event which adds a new row in the widget inside the view (handles as in, fires the method in the view which generates this new row), I could have a `getRowButtons(int index)` method in the view, and then using this to retrieve the components and bind them after they where added.

I'm sure there's a more clever way of doing this though, so I'm seeking a bit of advice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The second article in this series](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/webtoolkit/articles/mvp-architecture-2.html) shows a view which **does** have a reference to the presenter.

The view:

```
private Presenter<T> presenter;

public void setPresenter(Presenter<T> presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;
}
```

The presenter:

```
public interface Presenter<T> {
    void onAddButtonClicked();
    void onDeleteButtonClicked();
    void onItemClicked(T clickedItem);
    void onItemSelected(T selectedItem);
}
```

You could now define a method in the presenter interface which has a parameter which indicates which row was clicked. If you don't want to make the view aware of the presenter interface you could always choose to fire an event on the event bus which the presenter could respond to. Based on your question though, the first option seems a more reasonable answer.

Comment: first off, thanks for pointing me to the second article in the series. Thats most helpfull. I just want to point out though, I'm not really looking to make the presenter aware of the row clicks. I'm talking about binding events on widgets (in this case buttons living inside the row) which are added at runtime :) Having a reference to the presenter provides me with yet another option of doing this :) thanks :) +1

Comment: You're welcome. If you have a reference to the presenter you could always bind them using a somewhat generic function (e.g. bindDelete(HasClickHandlers hasClick, Person person)) and just register for the ClickEvents (but I think you already came to that conclusion ;)).